# Update query for two tables in oracle based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider i have two table train_reserve and reserve:

train_reserve:

| ChangeId | C_Id | Process | Download | trainId | Status | SDate | EDate | Book_date | L_date | BookId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 | A | 1995 | B | 05-APR-22 | 06-APR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 111 |
| 2 | 1001 | 2 | B | 1995 | M | 05-APR-22 | 08-APR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 111 |
| 3 | 1002 | 1 | B | 1995 | B | 12-APR-22 | 14-APR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 222 |
| 4 | 1002 | 2 | C | 1995 | M | 12-APR-22 | 13-APR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 222 |
| 5 | 1003 | 1 | A | 1995 | B | 25-MAY-22 | 25-MAY-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 333 |
| 6 | 1004 | 1 | A | 1995 | B | 19-MAR-22 | 20-MAR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 444 |
| 7 | 1004 | 1 | B | 1995 | B | 19-MAR-22 | 20-MAR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 555 |

reserve:

| C_Id | trainId | SDate | EDate | L_date | BookId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1995 | 05-APR-22 | 08-APR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 111 |
| 1002 | 1995 | 12-APR-22 | 13-APR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 222 |
| 1003 | 1995 | 25-MAY-22 | 25-MAY-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 333 |
| 1004 | 1995 | 19-MAR-22 | 20-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 444 |
| 1005 | 1995 | 19-MAR-22 | 20-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 555 |

Below is the input from user:
C_id=1, Process=(1,2), Download=(A,B,C), trainId=1995, Status=(B),Sdate=null,Edate=null,Book_date>='10-MAR-22',L_date=null.

User want to update BookId=null in both tables when C_id>=1001 and Status is B only . i.e I want below output:

train_reserve:

| ChangeId | C_Id | Process | Download | trainId | Status | SDate | EDate | Book_date | L_date | BookId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 | A | 1995 | B | 05-APR-22 | 06-APR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 111 |
| 2 | 1001 | 2 | B | 1995 | M | 05-APR-22 | 08-APR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 111 |
| 3 | 1002 | 1 | B | 1995 | B | 12-APR-22 | 14-APR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 222 |
| 4 | 1002 | 2 | C | 1995 | M | 12-APR-22 | 13-APR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 222 |
| 5 | 1003 | 1 | A | 1995 | B | 25-MAY-22 | 25-MAY-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | null |
| 6 | 1004 | 1 | A | 1995 | B | 19-MAR-22 | 20-MAR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | null |
| 7 | 1004 | 1 | B | 1995 | B | 19-MAR-22 | 20-MAR-22 | 10-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | null |

reserve:

| C_Id | trainId | SDate | EDate | L_date | BookId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1995 | 05-APR-22 | 08-APR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 111 |
| 1002 | 1995 | 12-APR-22 | 13-APR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | 222 |
| 1003 | 1995 | 25-MAY-22 | 25-MAY-22 | 11-MAR-22 | null |
| 1004 | 1995 | 19-MAR-22 | 20-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | null |
| 1005 | 1995 | 19-MAR-22 | 20-MAR-22 | 11-MAR-22 | null |

I am currently using two update statements as below

```
update train_reserve a
   set a.BookId=null
 where a.C_Id>=1001 
   and a.trainId=1995 
   and a.Process in (1,2) 
   and a.Download in ('A','B','C') 
   and a.Status='B' 
   and a.Book_date>='10-MAR-22' 
   and not exists (select 1 
                     from train_reserve b 
                    where a.C_Id = b.C_Id 
                      and b.Status='M');

update reserve 
   set BookId = null 
 where a.C_Id in (select a.C_Id 
                    from train_reserve a 
                   where a.C_Id >= 1001 
                     and a.trainId=1995 
                     and a.Process in (1,2) 
                     and a.Download in ('A','B','C') 
                     and a.Status='B' 
                     and a.Book_date>='10-MAR-22' 
                     and not exists (select 1 
                                       from train_reserve b 
                                      where a.C_Id = b.C_Id 
                                        and b.Status='M'));

But second query above takes long time to update since i am fetching data from 1st table then updating reserve table.

Is there optimized way to achieve above result?
```

Comment: Please post the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) of the second statement. Check the link for other information required, e.g. the  size of the table and how many rows do you expect to be updated. Available indexes / partitioning etc.

Comment: for Last 3 rows the BookId is expected to be updated as null, because for the last 3 rows a.C_Id >= 1001 and a.trainId=1995 and a.Process in (1,2) and a.Download in ('A','B','C')  and a.Status='B' and a.Book_date>='10-MAR-22' .